# how can i check a user is logged in a store from another store

Tags: magento, single-sign-on

There are two stores in my "Magento" website with two different domain names.
I have shared the domain in the customers configuration so if a user signs up for the first store, he can also sign in the second store with the same credentials.

Now what I want is if customer is logged in first store, that user automatically is logged in second store.

How can I do this? I though about cookies but I am not able to set a cookie for a different domain.

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Can you specify in detail how the `websites` and `store views` are set up?

Answer (score -1):

I am not a "Magento" guy, but I can suggest something for you scenario. If your user/login table is shared between your stores, then you have have a logged in flag, so if the user logs in to store1 set this flag, now if the user navigates to store2, you need to check this flag and based on the flag status you can create user session on store2

Comment: but how can i determine which user is login,either i have to trace ip.if i store ip then in every browser that user will het login.which is not.

Comment: I am not clear on this .. but regarding user check, if the user navigates to store2 from store1 you need to pass some identification eg. user id using which you can check the logged in status. If the user is already logged in, user will be allowed to enter store2 without explicitly loggin in otherwise login screen needs to be displayed.